# Finding limit points in lexicographic order topology

Tags: general-topology

If we consider the unit square (i.e $[0,1] \times [0,1]$) with the lexicographic
order induced by ${\mathbb{R}}^{2}$, what are the limit points of the unit square?

My answer is: the set of limit points is equal to:

$ [0,1]^{2} \setminus ((0,1) \times \{1\}))$.

Is my answer correct? If not, how do you find them? I get confused with this topology.

Comment: Try not to think of it in the sense of a square, but rather a linear order which has continuum-many copies of $[0,1]$ piled on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every point $P = (a,b)$ on the square lies on some horizontal line segment $y = b$.  If $a \neq 0$ -- i.e., if $P$ is not the leftmost point on its horizontal line segment -- then you can build a sequence of points $(x_n,b)$ to the left of $a$ on that line segment converging to $P$.  If $a \neq 1$ -- i.e., if $P$ is not the rightmost point on its horizontal line segment -- then you can build a sequence of points $(x_n,b)$ to the right of $a$ on that line segment converging to $(a,b)$.

Obviously $P$ can't be both the leftmost point *and* the rightmost point, so the conclusion is...