# Closure question

Tags: general-topology

> Determine the closures of the following subsets of the ordered square:
>
> $$A = \{(1/n) \times 0 : n \in Z_+ \}$$

The key says

$\bar{A} = A \cup \{ 0 \times 1 \}$

I thought it was $\bar{A} = A \cup \{ (0,0) \}$

why is it  $\bar{A} = A \cup \{ 0 \times 1 \}$?

Comment: https://www.math.lsu.edu/~stoltz/Courses/F08/7510/CourseMaterials/HW2ans.pdf I got it from this link

Comment: Well, that's a screwy to write the set.  What it means I assume is $A=${$(1/n,0):n\in \mathbb Z_+$}/

Comment: According to your notes for $A$ to be closed, $(1/n)$ needs to needs to be closed. Adjoining the limit points of this set is all you need to do to find the closure of $A$.

Comment: @Any, so then why am I wrong? Because I don't follow the other exercises either. My answers are all completely different

Comment: Well, I don't really know lexicographic order topology…that word kinda scares me and wikipedia just shows me a picture with a bunch of numbers.

Comment: So just always to the right?

Comment: @sidht it goes in vertical strips, then left to right.

Comment: Is it a stripe or a line? $(a,b)$ here represents a line segment in the square right?

Comment: You may find the following useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/15901/107693

Answer (score 2):

You have to notice that the topology is the **lexicographic order topology** on the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$: Define a linear order on the square by $(a,b)≤(c,d)$ if $a≤c$, or $a=c$ and $b≤d$. Sometimes referred to as the "dictionary" ordering for obvious reasons. Now you just give this set the order topology induced by ≤. An open set looks like a union of vertical open (in $[0,1]$) intervals.To picture this linear order: go from $(0,0)$ up to $(0,1)$, then start back at $(\epsilon ,0)$ and go up to $(\epsilon,1)$, back to $(2\epsilon,0)$, etc. As an exercise to test your understanding, prove that $\omega \times\mathbb [0,1)$, in the lexicographic order topology, is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$.

Now to to the problem. $(0,0)$ is NOT a limit point of $A$ in this topology: for instance, $0\times[0,1)$ is an open set containing $(0,0)$ but no points of $A$.

$(0,1)$, on the other hand, is a limit of $A$ in this topology:  An open set containing $(0,1)$ contains a set of the form $0\times (y,1] \cup (0,x)\times [0,1]$, which contains an entire tail of the sequence that makes up $A$.

The ordered square is Hausdorff, which implies uniqueness of sequential limits. Thus $\overline {A}=A\cup ${$(0,1)$}.

Comment: I understood the logic behind the solution clearly. Thanks, would have been better if you had used 0x1 for the point (0, 1) since that does cause a bit of confusion in notation.

Comment: @Forever Mozart I didn't understand why (0, 1) is limit point of A. Could you please explain in a simple way ?